# Extracting data from a non-formatted string

Tags: string, extract, text-extraction

I want to extract certain parts and be able to put it into a nice spreadsheet format. The important parts are the address, ward number, square feet, and price. I was going to try something really complicated in PHP(novice), but thought there might be an easier way.

The data looks like this:

```
243-467
1402 E. Mt. Pleasant Ave.     50th Ward approximately 1,416 sq. ft. more or less BRT# 502440300 Improvements: Residential Dwelling
JANET DENNIS     C.P. October Term, 2007 No. 01082     $105,641.01     Morton R. Branzburg, Esq. 

 244-712A
5407 Chestnut St. - Premise A     60th Ward Apt 2-4 Unts 2 sty Masonry; Improvement Area 4,610 sq. ft. BRT# 603011200 Improvements: Residential Dwelling
ALEXANDER TALMADGE, JR. (WHO HAS 1/3 INTEREST), BERNADINE ABAD AND BERNARD BLAIR TALMADGE         $32,153.00     Drew Salaman, Esq.
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the data come from? Can you modify its output? If so, try outputting CSV text (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Excel will import CSV files.

Comment: The data comes from: http://www.phillysheriff.com/old_site/properties.html, but it's not always published in html form, many times it's in a word doc.